# Updating themes and plugins automatically

Tags: wordpress

I want my plugins and themes to be updated automatically but I am unable to do it.

[This guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) says that you have to add

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

to the code, but I don't know where exactly should I add it. The guide also suggests to put it into mu-plugins but I have no idea how.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Updating Wordpress core:**

If you want the WordPress auto updates to handle major core updates too, you will have to add a single configuration line. To do this, open the ***wp-config.php*** file in the root folder of your WordPress installation and add this line to it:

```
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);
```

**2. Updating Wordpress plugins:**

If you want your plugins to be automatically updated by WordPress when a new version is released, you need to add a line to your ***wp-config.php*** file, similar to the one above. This time, however, a filter is used for enabling the plugin auto updates:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

**3. Updating Wordpress themes:**

If you want WordPress to handle themes updates you need another line added to the ***wp-config.php*** file:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );
```

If you are getting problem like this - *Do not add add_filter() calls in wp-config.php - causes conflicts with WP-CLI and possibly other problems.* Then should have to put these filters into [mu-plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer :) When I put it into wp-config, the site stops working. There is this sentence in the guide "Do not add add_filter() calls in wp-config.php - causes conflicts with WP-CLI and possibly other problems."

Comment: @Lenka: May I know your Wordpress version, please?

Comment: @Lenka: Put these filters in a must-use plugin. [Must Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

Comment: How do I do that, though? I tried creating a folder "mu-plugins" and adding php file with the filters in it but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Lenka: May I know which version of wordpress are you using?
Cause in the latest version auto update feature is available.

Comment: @Lenka: For mu-plugins just create a directory named "mu-plugins" under .../wp-content/. Then create my_mu_plugin.php. Write plugin headers and your code into it. In this case above mentioned filters.

Comment: I use the version 4.3.1.

Comment: @Lenka: You can use plugin [Advanced Automatic Updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-updater/changelog/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code to `functions.php` file in your theme folder, so use FTP to add this line to `wp-contemt/themes/YOUR-THEME-NAME/functions.php`

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) I put add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' ); and add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' ); to functions.php but plugins still aren't updated automatically. Should I perhaps clear the cache or something?

Comment: This is the wrong place for the code - see the answer from Aviator